# How to measure time within matlab generated C/C++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, time, matlab-coder

I have some matlab code that I use to generate C++ code with, using `codegen`. I want to check the execution time of a single function within this code. Normally I would use `tic` and `toc` but these functions are not supported for code generation. Is there a way to measure execution time of a single function within a generated matlab function?

Comment: You can try manually insert time measurement code in C++, after finding the relevant section in the generated code (compile, and execute the code with time measurement included).

Comment: This [technical article](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/using-legacy-code-with-matlab-coder.html) from the MathWorks might help.